# Prove that $g''(x) = -g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation, solution-verification, elementary-functions

> Suppose $f$ is a differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f''(x) = −f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.
>   Set $$g(x) = f(x) − f(0)C(x) − f'(0)S(x)$$
>   Prove that
>   $$g''(x) = −g(x),\quad\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$ and $$g^k(0) = 0, \quad\forall k \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$$
>
> Note:
>   $C(x) = \cos(x) = \frac {e^{ix}+e^{−ix}}{2}$ and $S(x) = \sin(x) =\frac {e^{ix}-e^{−ix}}{2i}$ where $i = \sqrt {-1}$ and $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n!}$.

I derived $g(x)$ twice but it gives me $g''(x)= -f(x) +4f(0)C(x) + 4f'(0)S(x)$
I'm not sure what went wrong, maybe I made a mistake in the derivation process, but I can't seem to figure out where.

Comment: Where did you get the factor $4$ from ? Unless you show how you got it we cannot tell you what went wrong.

Comment: What did you get for $g'(x)$? If you got $f'(x)+f(0)S(x)-f'(0)C(x)$, then you did that part right and the mistake is in going from there to $g''(x)$. If you got something else, then there was already a mistake in computing $g'(x)$.

Comment: $C$ and $S$ are indeed $\sin$ and $\cos$, so you shouldn't be getting those factors of 4 when differentiating. (Note that the correct word is "differentiate", not "derive".)

Comment: Thank you everyone, I realised I made a huge mistake in my computation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the leading coefficients of the C(x) and S(x) are constants, and g(x) is linear in C(x), S(x), and f(x), you simply need to show their individual functions also obey the sign property of f, that is $f'' = -f$. They do, you made an algebra mistake somewhere.